# Where did I go wrong here? Answer to question migrated into SF deleted by community

Tags: discussion

One of my [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/422365/33193) to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/422364/how-do-i-securely-share-my-server/422365#422365) got deleted by community.
Now, as I understand it, community handles automatic tasks, and so this might have not been done by an admin. Now, it isn't about the rep, but If there's something obviously wrong with this answer, I'd like to know what, so I can avoid pitfalls that would result in an invalid answer. As far as I see it, there's nothing *obviously* wrong with the answer.

I'm not sure if its related to [this](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3708/why-was-a-question-i-answered-automatically-deleted) but its possible

Answer (score 7):

According to [this MSO Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138460/189912), when a migration is rejected, answers which were migrated along with the question are deleted. The reason for this is that the answers are [returned to the source site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/189912), where the question could potentially be reopened or sent elsewhere.